# Create separate Django Admin sites and separate permissions

Tags: python, django

In Django, i have extend the AdminSite class into a UserAdminSite class. But there is a problem: Any Admin who has access to the UserAdminSite would also have a "is_staff = True" status and could therefore access the default admin site for the entire website. How do I separate the access permission for these two admin sites?

Comment: Isn't that admin supposed to have full access? perhaps you should consider making that **admin** a staff and use group permission to differentiate who can access to either site.

Comment: The admin for the UserAdminSite should only have access to User and Group management while the admin for the default admin site have access to all the models of the site. How do I use group permission to differentiate that specifically?

Comment: Simply put, that `admin` for `UserAdminSite` is not an actual **admin**, but a **staff** with `UserAdminSite` permissions on `Users` and `Groups`.

Comment: alternatively you can customise `User` model with an attribute to differentiate their role either on `UserAdminSite` or **both**, override `is_superuser` to check their role, too.

Comment: However one concern has to be taken care, if that `staff` has access to `User` and `Groups`, one can alter their own permissions to have full access. I think better solution could really be writing a custom `UserManager` and implement the alternatives

Answer (score 1):

Under Site Administration:  Add a new "Group"; then select which permissions you want to give any user assigned to that group.

After creating the new group, then assign the user to that group.